# Who bet against the usefulness of matrix inversion – or is it a myth?

Tags: mathematics, reference-request, linear-algebra, computation, anecdote

In my linear-algebra and numerics courses, I frequently heard an anecdote about some professor betting – literally, with money – that there would never be any application where computing the actual inverse of a matrix was the best option. (Obviously, some fineprint needs to be added to that bet, but that’s not pertinent here.)

Who was this and what was the actual bet? Or is it just a myth? Given that there is no shortage of myths, I only care about anything coming with a trustworthy reference.

Comment: And assuming it happened, what was the outcome of the bet?

Comment: @HansOlsson: Well, unless I am mistaken, we haven’t found any application fitting the criteria yet, i.e., “never invert a matrix” still holds.

Comment: I would also assume so.

Comment: There are arguments against inverting matrices for applications, see https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/26423/practical-example-of-why-it-is-not-good-to-invert-a-matrix

Comment: Can anybody elaborate to me why this got three “blatantly off-topic” close votes?

Comment: The sentiment is common, but the two oft-cited reasons for it (inaccuracy and inefficiency) are, at least sometimes, erroneous, see [Druinsky-Toledo](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.6035). And considering how often the sentiment is repeated without mentioning the anecdote, I suspect that it is a local fabrication specific to the place where you heard it. It did not make it into the big times on the internet (yet) :)

Comment: Matrix inversion happens all the time, and has for a long long time. My numerical methods professor many moons ago never told such a tale, and he was active from the 50's onward.